# Getting Error in Bulkcreate in NODE Sequalize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

getting this error when inserting an array of objects. The target table 'skill_group_users' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without the INTO clause.

input is

```
[
    {
        "id": "676",
        "key": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "677",
        "key": "test"
    }
]

return await this.models.table.bulkCreate(entities);
```

i have already added in model

```
const options = {
    tableName: 'table',
    timestamps: false,
    hasTrigger: true,
  };
```

it works with create but not with `bulkCreate`. I have an after insert, delete and update trigger on that table. please provide a solution or another way?

Comment: INSERT INTO [table] ([id],[key]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (N\'676\',N\'test\'),(N\'677\',N\'test\'); making this query.

Answer (score 3):

resolved issue. by putting returning false.

const result = await this.models.skill_group_users.bulkCreate(data, {
      returning: false,
    });

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution, I was stuck for a long time due to this